# Can't get Windows 8 to not show password screen

Tags: windows, windows-8

I'm having a problem with my Windows 8 Pro.
I don't want Windows to display the "enter your password" screen after I resume from standby/hibernation.

Now I have disabled the lock screen in GPO and everywhere I could find I disabled the "ask for password when Windows resumes" option.

[image: Power Options]

[image: System Settings]

But to no avail. Windows keep asking for my password whenever it resumes. I have a local account if that matters anything. I suspect this is a bug, but can't find anyone else having problems with it.

Comment: Did you disable it in: PC Settings>Users and under "Sign-in options" and the "Change" button under "Any user who has a password must enter it when waking this PC?"